# `No instance for System.Random.Random` on a custom typeclass when using `choose`

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am doing an exercise in Haskell Programming from First Principles. It asks me to generate equal probabilities, and 1/3, 2/3 probabilities from each of:

```
data Fool =
  Fulse
  | Frue
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And my answer is

```
module Random where

-- import Test.Hspec
import Test.QuickCheck

data Fool =
  Fulse
  | Frue
  deriving (Eq, Show)


genFool :: Gen Fool
genFool = choose (Fulse, Frue)

genFool' :: Gen Fool
genFool' = do
  frequency [(2, return Fulse)
            ,(1, return Frue)]
```

but `genFool` is wrong. The error message is :

```
../chap14/random.hs:13:11: error:
    • No instance for (System.Random.Random Fool)
        arising from a use of ‘choose’
    • In the expression: choose (Fulse, Frue)
      In an equation for ‘genFool’: genFool = choose (Fulse, Frue)
   |
13 | genFool = choose (Fulse, Frue)
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Previously I have some code like this:

```
genBool :: Gen Bool
genBool = choose (False, True)
```

which works properly. I think there may be some predefined `instance` of `System.Random.Random Fool` to make the `choose` work.

What should I do to make the my version of `genFool` compile?

And btw, why is the `return Fulse` in the second `genFool'` of type `Gen Fool`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Test.Quickcheck` module's `choose` function has the following type signature:

```
choose :: Random a => (a, a) -> Gen a
```

So, if you are planning to use `choose` function on your `Fool` type, it has to be made instance of `Random` typeclass as seen in the above type signature.

This is where [Random typeclass](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.14/random-1.1/System-Random.html#t:Random) is defined. It needs either a minimal implementation of either `randomR` and `random`.

Since your type `Fool` has only two values, it's isomorphic to `Bool` type. So, you can define a function mapping the values appropriately:

```
mapBool :: Bool -> Fool
mapBool False = Fulse
mapBool True = Frue
```

And then you can define a typeclass instance for your type:

```
instance Random Fool where
    random g = let (b :: Bool, g') = random g
               in (mapBool b, g')
    randomR _ g = (random g) -- Note that this doesn't work correctly. You need to pattern match and fix this.
```

The above code should make your module compile fine.

Comment: No, a minimal definition needs both `randomR` and `random`.

Comment: No extension is needed; your type annotation is redundant.

Comment: @cmal I have given a sample implementation of `randomR`. Note that the first argument to `randomR` is a range. Since your type only contains two values, I'm skipping them entirely. You can modify it if you need a different behavior.

Comment: Your implementation returns invalid results if you do e.g. `randomR (Frue, Frue)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to implement randomR and random like the following, what should I change to make it compile? `instance Random Fool where randomR (Frue, Frue) g = (Frue,g) randomR (Fulse, x) g = do b <- getStdRandom (randomR (True, False)) return $ (if b then x else Fulse,g) random g = do b <- getStdRandom (randomR (True, False)) return $ if b then Frue else Fulse` Currently the error message is Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘(,) Fool’ ... b <- getStdRandom (randomR (True, False))

Comment: @melpomene Yeah, I know. The proper implemntation is : ```    randomR (Frue, Frue) g = (Frue, g)
    randomR (Fulse, Fulse) g = (Fulse, g)
    randomR _ g = random g
``` . But I think OP will be able to figure out from here.

Comment: @cmal You shouldn't have a `do` block there (or call `getStdRandom`).

Comment: Can you show me some code of `random g = ???`? Thanks a lot. @melpomene

Comment: @cmal It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940687/no-instance-for-system-random-random-on-a-custom-typeclass-when-using-choose/52940820#comment92791019_52940820

Comment: @Sibi hi, it only defines `randomR`, but not `random g`. How to implement the `random g` ? Thanks!

Comment: @cmal `random g` is defined in my answer.